# Decomposing the "sign flip" matrix in terms of Pauli matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quantum-computation

Can the matrix:

$A=\left[\begin{matrix}0 & -1 \\ -1 & 0\end{matrix}\right]$

be somehow expressed as a product of the $3$ standard Pauli matrices?

I'm being able to diagonalize $A$, but not sure if it can be expressed in terms of Pauli-X, Y, Z.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I start by knowing that the flip operator is $F=-\sigma_1$.

Then to express as a product of all the sigma matrices we just find a combination which reduces to the negative identity.

The relation

$$\sigma_1^2 = \sigma_2^2=\sigma_3^2=-i\sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma_3 = 1$$

lets us construct $(\sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma_3)^2 = -1$ to get

$$F=-\sigma_1(\sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma_3)^2$$
 $$\require{cancel} F=-\cancel{\sigma_1\sigma_1}\sigma_2\sigma_3\sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma_3$$

We can also recover the solution provided by [@euler-is-alive](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2864842/272850) because $\sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma_3=i$ is just a number and so we can freely rearrange as $\sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma_3\sigma_2\sigma_3$

Comment: More of a comment but I also thought it's interesting that $F = -\sigma_1 = i\sigma_2\sigma_3$

Answer (score 3):

$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1\\ -1 & 0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -i\\ i & 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -i\\ i & 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix} $

Comment: Nice! How exactly did you come up with the decomposition?

Comment: You're probably not going to like my answer.  I had never heard of the Pauli Matrices before, so I looked them up on Wikipedia, and played around with them for about 5 minutes finding out some properties.  There may very well in fact be other decompositions that are more useful for what you are looking for.

Comment: (Note that since the matrices are involutory, the last 4 terms are simply the multiplicative commutator).